# AngularJS service not invoking error callback on save() method

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

So I'm using angularjs restful service $resource and I'm calling $save function.  However, the error callback I pass to it is not being called.  The server is sending a 418 error which I thought since it's NOT 200 would result in the error callback being invoked.  But, it never does.  I can't find any documentation stating what http error codes will result in the error callback being called.

Here is my code:

```
var modalScope = $scope.$new();
modalScope.showPassword = false;
modalScope.message = null;
modalScope.user = new User();

modalScope.submit = function(user) {
    user.$save( {}, function(data,headers) {
        // do the success case
    }, function(data,headers) {
        // do the error case                
    });
};
```

The modalScope.user is being passed to the submit function defined.  So what's the problem why this error callback isn't being called?

Comment: So, `success` callback is always called?

Comment: Yes the success callback is always called.

Comment: I think I found the problem, your webserver is a teapot.

Comment: If you use *interceptors* make sure you return rejected response in error handers `return $q.reject(rejection);` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the following in the ngResource source code

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with status
        // code outside of the <200, 400) range
    });
```

I am kind of confused about the range notation but it seems it should actually call the error method. Maybe you found a bug.

Comment: Angularjs documentation is absolutely abysmal.  They are truly awful.  I can't say enough how terribly terribly terrible they are at explaining themselves.  That being said I think anything between 100-200, 400-499 are NOT considered errors.  WTF?!  Right?!  How the hell does that make any sense.  A 404 would be an error!  What page in the docs did you find that?  I'll post a comment asking them to clarify and potentially change their insipid policy.

Comment: Crap I re-read your comment.  It was in the source code.  Yay for documentation.  Anyway thank you for finding that!

Comment: @chubbsondubs I didn't find it in the docs but in the angular source code. Search for "400)" here to find the passage: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js

Comment: FWIW, the "<200, 400) range" comment is in the docs, but it is on the $http page, under section "General usage": http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http  
The $resource page indicates that the $resource service uses the lower-level $http service underneath, so you'd have to follow that documentation trail to find it.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Good to know! Then I don't need to search the source code again. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and nothing here worked. Turned out I had an custom debug-interceptor that didn't explicitly return a $q.reject(response).

Apparently every custom debug-interceptor completely overwrites the default behavior.

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2609#issuecomment-44452795 for where I found the answer.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Thanks for this!

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. The problem was in one of our interceptors. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I had troubles with the error callback as well, but it appears that in more recent versions of AngularJS, the error callback method must now be implemented something like this:

```
SomeResource.query({}, angular.noop, function(response){
  $scope.status = response.status; 
});
```

Source + more detailed description: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/3Q-Ip95GViI/at8cF5LsMHwJ

Also, in response to the comments on Flek's post, it seems that now only responses between 200 and 300 are not considered an error.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get Alter's answer to work, but this worked for me:

```
user.$save(function (user, headers) {
                    // Success
                    console.log("$save success " + JSON.stringify(user));
                }, function (error) {
                    // failure
                    console.log("$save failed " + JSON.stringify(error))
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying from the [ngResource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
> invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
>
> Success callback is called with (value, responseHeaders) arguments. Error callback is called with (httpResponse) argument.

`$save` is considered as a non-GET "class" action, so you must to use an extra `postData` parameter. Using the same question example, this should work:

```
modalScope.submit = function(user) {
    user.$save( {}, {}, function(data,headers) {
        // do the success case
    }, function(response) {
        // do the error case                
    });
};
```

Keep an eye on the error callback, compared with the example, is calling with just one argument, which brings all the http response.

Comment: Isn't $save() an instance action making the error callback the third parameter?

Answer (score -1):

Actually if we follow the documentation. it works

```
 User.save(vm.user, function (response) {
              FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
              $location.path('/login');
      },
      function (response) {

          FlashService.Error(response.data);
          vm.dataLoading = false;

      });
```

above is snip from my code it works.