# Error callback on resource method

Tags: angularjs, callback, resources

I'm trying to do different actions when getting 409 response from the server on a resource's method.

Basically I have the same problem as in [AngularJS service not invoking error callback on save() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080877/angularjs-service-not-invoking-error-callback-on-save-method), I've tried all the answers but I always get the success callback.

```
    $scope.form.$save(function (data, headers) {
        console.log(data, headers);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('fail');
    });
```

Can anyone give a definitive answer if this is fixed, and if / what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had an custom debug-interceptor that didn't explicitly return a $q.reject(response).

Apparently every custom debug-interceptor completely overwrites the default behavior.
See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2609#issuecomment-44452795 for where I found the answer.