# handle error callback on save() method $ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I need to handle error callback of an update operation, for this i'm using method `save()` like this:

```
$scope.save = function (params) {  
  MigParams.save(params);
};
```

`Migparams` service look like this:

```
angular.module('monitor').
    factory('MigParams', function ($resource) {        
        return $resource('/restful/migparams');    
});
```

This code works great but i need to know if an error occurs in database. I have searched in google but i didn't find this particular case. Is there a way of get this?.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource:

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
>
> non-GET "class" instance: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])

`$resource`'s save method falls into the non-GET 'class' instance category), so its error callback is the third argument.

Your code would look like:

```
$scope.save = function (params) {  
  MigParams.save(params, 
    function(resp, headers){
      //success callback
      console.log(resp);
    },
    function(err){
      // error callback
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this worked, but i used `save` insetead `$save` and removed second parameter `{}`.

Comment: Ah ok, cool. I edited my answer to match what worked for you (no second {} param, and using save instead of $save)

Comment: It still takes me in success callback on errors. What can be the reason?

Comment: I am sending a SC_BAD_REQUEST = 400 back and angular is still using the success function instead of the error function. So same problem as Hussain is having I guess?

Comment: Read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080877/angularjs-service-not-invoking-error-callback-on-save-method
Maybe 400 is not seen as an error in Angular. Hussain, look at what code you are returning. Also check your interceptors (again see thread for more info).