# angularjs ngResource success undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have an ngResource factory like so:

```
app.service 'Api', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    {
        Student: $resource "/api/v1/students/:id", {id: "@id", option: "@option"}, { 'update': {method: 'PUT'}}
]
```

I have a controller like so:

```
app.controller 'newStudentCtrl', ($scope, $state, Api) ->

    $scope.addNewStudent = ->
        student = Api.Student.save(
            student: $scope.newStudent
            )
        console.log(student.id)
        $state.go('student.new', { id: student.id})
```

The new Student record is saved, but student.id is returning undefined.

console.log(student) is returning the following:

```
Resource {student: Object, $promise: Promise, $resolved: false....
$promise: Promise
$resolved: true
id: 88
last_name: "Baggins"
```

How do I handle the success callback to get the student.id?

Comment: Is id being generated from DB or from front end?

Comment: From the DB. The student.id value is definitely in the server response, but I've tried the sample code in the docs to get it to no avail.

Comment: What does this gives console.log(id)? id or undefined

Comment: It's ok Reena, I've solved the problem and will post an answer. Thanks for trying to help! You're a champ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$scope.addNewStudent = -> 
Api.Student.save { student: $scope.newStudent}, ((successResponse, headers) ->
    console.log successResponse.id
     ....
```

The solution was given here:

[handle error callback on save() method $ngResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405016/handle-error-callback-on-save-method-ngresource)